# python matplotlib: can I add markers to a stackplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, markers

I am creating a stacked plot with the following code. Is there any way I can add markers to the plot? I know it's possible with plot and scatter, but stackplot doesn't accept the 'marker' parameter. Thanks!

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.ones((10,2)),columns=['field1','field2'])
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
plt.suptitle('This is a plot of ABCDEF')
ax.stackplot(df.index,df.field1,df.field2]
```

Comment: just make another plotting call with `ax.plot` as you say in your question.

Comment: I think you have a typo: the last ``]`` should be a ``)``. Any reason why you can't just ``ax.plot(df.index, df.field1, 'o');ax.plot(df.index,df.field2,'x')``?

Comment: Almost what @Jose specified -- `ax.plot(df.index, df.field0, 'o')` will be right, but you'll need `ax.plot(df.index, df.field0 + df.field1, 'h')` for the next set. A simple stackplot adds up the y-values to stack them (instead of overlaying them).